Capacitor Android issue splash screen instead of camera
I am using to scan the qr code this plugin: @capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning.
It was working fine, after that i added the splash image on Android I see the splash screen instead of the camera.
The plugin still works and is able to scan the qr code, but on the screen i don't see the camera but the splash.
Any idea on this issue?
